# ls there a way to connect to database from SQL and get data and execute r or python script using Microsoft SSIS

Tags: python, r, ssis, ssms

What I want to do is to connect the database from SQL and transfer the r or python code I wrote to SSIS and make it callable and transfer the output to the table in SSMS.

I don't know how to make the code in a format that can generate output by using the data I added to SSIS

Comment: If you are using SQL Server 2017+, then it has support to execute both R and Python as an external script in T-SQL. If you want to execute Python/R directly in SSIS, you're going to want an Execute Process Task. I'm not really sure what SSMS, an IDE-like application for SQL Server, has to do with the question though. Are you, perhaps, using SSMS to actually refer to SQL Server? This is like calling SSIS "Visual Studio". SSMS and SQL Server are *not* the same; SSMS is the tool you use to work with SQL Server; SQL Server is the RDBMS.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes actually I mean SQL server, I am trying execute process task. but how should retrieve the data, how should I make the code suitable for it?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, you have some Python or R code that gets data, does something and now you want to store it into a table.

Depending on volume of data, etc, maybe you just enumerate through your data and issue singleton INSERT statements. I've had a devil of a time getting a bulk insert to work with Python and don't R enough to have an opinion on the matter.

The only thing SSIS is going to do for you in this situation is be an orchestrator. To run a Python script, you're going to use an Execute Process Task.

An alternative, depending on libraries needed and such, is to take advantage of [sp_execute_external_script](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-execute-external-script-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16) It allows for the execution of code within the context of the database (without the risk of actually executing in SQL's address space) so your data stays on the server and then you can either pipe it out to a table or if you need to then do SSIS things with it, use that as a source in a dataflow and then you can make use of the manipulations built-in.